# Passing C++ array to Fortran subroutine causes nan values to appear in result

Tags: c++, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm trying to use Fortran code from a C++ application. Specifically, I am trying to interface with SLATEC's [drc3jj.f](http://www.netlib.org/slatec/src/drc3jj.f). However, the Fortran subroutine returns an array which size depends on the parameters passed to the function.

If the size of the array is 1, then the C++ array that I print contains the appropriate value. However, if this size is greater than one, the C++ array contains NaNs where there should be output values.

Below is the code I use. This merely links the Fortran subroutine to the C++ application.

```
#ifndef FORTRANLINKAGE_H
#define FORTRANLINKAGE_H

extern "C"
{
    extern void drc3jj_(double*,double*,double*,double*,double*,
                        double*,double [],int*,int*);
}

#endif // FORTRANLINKAGE_H
```

The meat is down here. We actually call the Fortran subroutine from C++ and print the output:

```
#include "fortranLinkage.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void wigner3j(double l2, double l3, double m2, double m3, double coeff [])
{
    double l1min,l1max;
    int ierr,size(3);

    drc3jj_(&l2,&l3,&m2,&m3,&l1min,&l1max,coeff,&size,&ierr);

    cout << "Min: " << l1min << "\t Max: " << l1max << "\t Err: " << ierr << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int l1(atoi(argv[1])),l2(atoi(argv[2])),m2(atoi(argv[3])),m3(atoi(argv[4]));
    double coeff [3];

    wigner3j(l1,l2,m2,m3,coeff);

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
          cout << coeff[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If we call the program with `./myProgram 2 8 2 8`, it properly outputs 1/sqrt(21). However, if we try `./myProgram 2 8 2 7`, where the size of the array is actually 2, we get this result:

```
Min: 9   Max: 10     Err: 0
-nan
-nan
2.08175e-317
```

The NaNs actually have the proper sign.

Anyway, is there another (proper) way to pass C++ arrays to Fortran? Is this even the issue?

Comment: looks like you need to pass as pointer &coeff. dont the docs for the fortranlinkage module address this?

Comment: @george I tried, compiler says: `test.cpp:13:58: error: cannot convert ‘double**’ to ‘double*’ for argument ‘7’`. When I try to pass it as `&coeff[0]`, I get the same error as before. There is no module, the code I posted is the whole code I use.

Comment: fix double [] to double * in the template..

Comment: @george Did that too, does not solve the issue.

Comment: Hmmm.  On the other hand, my answer below might not address the real problem at all.  drc3jj depends on 2 other routines - one for printing error messages, and one (`d1mach`) for calculating machine constants.  As far as I can see, the results of d1mach aren't used in the first case (2 8 2 8) but are in the second (..2 7).  Is there a possibility that your `d1mach` is broken? How are you compiling/linking it?  In particular, if you edit `drc3jj.f` to replace all occurences of `huge` with `hval` and change `HUGE = SQRT(D1MACH(2)...)` to `HVAL = SQRT(HUGE(1.D0)...)`, does it work?

Comment: Doing as you suggest gives me: `g++-4.6 test.cpp wigner_wrap.f90 drc3jj.f utils.f -lgfortran
drc3jj.f:144.13:

      HVAL = SQRT(HUGE(1.0D0)/20.0D0)                                   
             1
Error: Arithmetic overflow converting REAL(8) to REAL(4) at (1). This check can be disabled with the option -fno-range-check`

Using your ISO_C_BINDING does not result the issue. utils.f contains all the dependencies of `drc3jj.f`, including `d1mach.f`. I took them directly from netlig.org.

Comment: @JonathanDursi Right you are. I used [this](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f77_src/machine/machine.f) version of d1mach and it worked. I also noticed that the use of ISO C Binding sometimes causes problems. In fact, running the program several times in a row reveals that sometimes it works, and sometimes returns with ier=5: size of the array too small. Reverting to the "old way" of doing things seems always yields a correct answer.

Comment: The problem is that everything is hardcoded in to d1mach; the right (modern) way to do things is with the `huge()` intrinsic.  Did you declare HVAL?  As double precision?  As to the other case, my guess is that the stricter checking of the `iso_c_binding` is catching something, but without examples it's hard to see what.

Comment: Well, using the code you submitted, compiling  and running `./a.out 2 8 2 7` repeatedly, I either get the correct answer or `$ ./a.out 2 8 2 7
 ***MESSAGE FROM ROUTINE DRC3JJ IN LIBRARY SLATEC.
 ***POTENTIALLY RECOVERABLE ERROR, PROG ABORTED, TRACEBACK REQUESTED
 *  Dimension of result array for 3j coefficients too small.
 *  ERROR NUMBER = 5
 *   
 ***END OF MESSAGE
 
 ***JOB ABORT DUE TO UNRECOVERED ERROR.
0          ERROR MESSAGE SUMMARY
 LIBRARY    SUBROUTINE MESSAGE START             NERR     LEVEL     COUNT
 SLATEC     DRC3JJ     Dimension of result          5         1         1
`

Comment: @JonathanDursi Never mind. While using ISO C Binding, I was passing ndim by reference, which was causing this error. I should have thought of it.

Comment: @JonathanDursi As for the `d1mach` issue, you were right. I had _not_ declared `HVAL` . So you're saying that this complicated machine constants stuff is encapsulated in a `huge()` intrinsic?

Comment: Most of the values `d1mach` returns are now available in intrinsics as of fortran95: [`huge()`](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/huge), [`tiny()`](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/tiny), [`epsilon()`](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/epsilon), [`spacing()`](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/spacing),  and those are guaranteed to give the right values for the platform and variable type; and of course it's one less routine to find the right version of and link in.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35617/discussion-between-joey-dumont-and-jonathan-dursi)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue resides not in the interface between C++ and Fortran, but rather in the obsolete Fortran implementation. The file drc3jj.f is part of the SLATEC library, which has utility functions that return constants that depend on the machine it's being run on (machine constants). They are defined in files `d1mach.f`, `i1mach.f` and `r1mach.f`.

However, since Fortran 95, there exists intrinsics such as `huge()`, `tiny()`, `spacing()` and `epsilon()` that are guaranteed to return the proper values for any machine.

The solution, then, is to remove any reference to `d1mach(int)` in the `drc3jj()` subroutine and replace them with the appropriate intrinsics.

Moreover, linking directly to the Fortran subroutines can always be tricky because it's compiler dependent; better is to use `iso_c_binding` in fortran90 to define the interface to C for you in a typesafe way:

```
!wrapper.f90:

subroutine drc3jj_wrap(l2, l3, m2, m3, l1min, l1max, thrcof, ndim, ier) bind(C)

    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    real(c_double), value, intent(in)           :: l2, l3, m2, m3
    real(c_double), intent(out)                 :: l1min, l1max
    real(c_double), dimension(ndim), intent(out):: thrcof
    integer (c_int), value, intent(in)          :: ndim
    integer (c_int), intent(out)                :: ier

    interface
          SUBROUTINE DRC3JJ (L2, L3, M2, M3, L1MIN, L1MAX, THRCOF, NDIM, IER)
              INTEGER NDIM, IER
              DOUBLE PRECISION L2, L3, M2, M3, L1MIN, L1MAX, THRCOF(NDIM)
          end SUBROUTINE DRC3JJ
    end interface

    call DRC3JJ(l2, l3, m2, m3, l1min, l1max, thrcof, ndim, ier)

end subroutine drc3jj_wrap
```

and

```
// fortranLinkage2.h
#ifndef FORTRANLINKAGE_H
#define FORTRANLINKAGE_H

extern "C"
{
    extern void drc3jj_wrap(double l2, double l3, double m2, double m3,
                            double *l1max, double *l2max, double *thrcof,
                            int ndim, int *ier);
}

#endif // FORTRANLINKAGE_H
```

and then you just call

```
void wigner3j(double l2, double l3, double m2, double m3, double coeff [])
{
    double l1min,l1max;
    int ierr,size(3);

    drc3jj_wrap(l2,l3,m2,m3,&l1min,&l1max,coeff,size,&ierr);

    cout << "Min: " << l1min << "\t Max: " << l1max << "\t Err: " << ierr << endl;
}
```

and compiling and running gives

```
$ g++ -c foo2.cc
$ gfortran -c wrapper.f90 
$ gfortran -c drc3jj.f 
$ g++ -o foo2 foo2.o wrapper.o drc3jj.o -lgfortran
$ ./foo2 2 8 2 8
Min: 10  Max: 10     Err: 0
0.218218
2.07738e-317
0
gpc-f103n084-$ ./foo2 2 8 2 7
Min: 9   Max: 10     Err: 0
-0.102598
-0.19518
0
```